# Update data in view when event happens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an Angular app that takes a large complex data set, and allows the user to filter it down using select lists. When data is filtered, a Google Map object is updated to display associated locations with the items that have been filtered.

I am trying to work it so that when the user clicks on a map pin, the filtered list of data is updated with only the items that are associated with that location.

Some snippets of the code:

```js
$scope.showInfoWindow = function(event, site) {

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(site.Latitude, site.Longitude);

  infowindow.setContent(
    '<h3>' + site.SiteName + '</h3>' + '<p>' + site.Address1 + '<br/>' + site.Address2 + '<br/>' + site.City + ', ' + site.State + ' ' + site.ZipCode + '</p>');

  infowindow.setPosition(center);
  infowindow.open($scope.map);

  $scope.findSelectedLocations(site.SiteName);

};

$scope.findSelectedLocations = function(SiteName) {

    $scope.filteredData.forEach(function(itemElement, itemIndex) {
      itemElement.Locations.forEach(function(locationElement, locationIndex) {
        locationElement.Sites.forEach(function(siteElement, siteIndex) {
          if (siteElement.SiteName == SiteName) {
            console.log('match!');
            console.log('itemIndex: ' + itemIndex);
            console.table(itemElement);

            $scope.$apply(function() {

              $scope.filteredData == itemElement;

            });

            return false;
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

```html
<div class="trials-item-outer-wrapper">

  <div class="trials-item-wrapper" du-scroll-container>

    <!-- start of row -->

    <div class="trials-item {{class}}" ng-repeat="data in (filteredData = (dataObject | byCountry : selectRegion | byRegion : selectState | byCity : selectCity | filterBy:['Phase']: selectPhase | filterBy:['Compound']: selectCompound | filterBy:['TherapeuticArea', 'TherapeuticArea_2',]: selectTherapy : 'strict' | unique: 'Id' | orderBy:'Phase' : reverse)) track by $index "
    ng-class="{'open':$index == selectedRow}" id="anchor-{{$index}}">

      <div class="trials-item-cell-wrapper">

        <div class="trials-item-cell">
          <img ng-click="toggleOpen($index, data.Compound,data.Number)" ng-src="assets/img/phase{{ data.Phase}}.png" width="54" height="61" alt="Phase {{ data.Phase}}" class="trials-item-phase-icon">
        </div>
        <div class="trials-item-cell"><a ng-click="toggleOpen($index, data.Compound,data.Number)"><span class="compound">{{ data.Compound }}</span><br/>{{ data.Compound_2 }}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="trials-item-cell">
          <a href="" ng-click="toggleOpen($index, data.Compound,data.Number)">
            <p class="trial-title">{{ data.TitleShort }}</p>
            <p>{{ data.Number }} {{ data.Status }}</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="trials-item-cell">
          <a href="" ng-click="toggleOpen($index, data.Compound,data.Number)"> 
      {{ data.TherapeuticArea }}<span ng-if="data.TherapeuticArea_2">, {{ data.TherapeuticArea_2 }}</span>
     </a> 
        </div>

        <div class="trials-item-cell location-cell">

          <span ng-if="data.Disclaimer">
      <p>{{data.Disclaimer}}</p></span>
        </div>

        <div class="trials-item-cell cart-actions">

          <div ng-if="!isInCart(data.Id)" class="add-to-cart">
            <a href="" ng-click="addToCartModalOpen($index, data, data.Id)">
              <img src="assets/img/cart-add.png" width="73" height="65" alt="Cart Add">
              <span>Add to Cart</span>
            </a>
          </div>


          <div ng-if="isInCart(data.Id)" class="remove-from-cart">
            <a href="" ng-click="removeFromCart(data.Id)">
              <img src="assets/img/cart-added.png" width="73" height="65" alt="Cart Add">
              <span>Remove from Cart</span>
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="trials-item-cell">
          <a ng-click="toggleOpen($index, data.Compound,data.Number)">
            <p class="more-text"></p>
            <div class="more glyphicon"></div>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- trials-item-cell-wrapper -->

      <div class="trials-tabs" ng-include="data.Url"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- end of ng-repeat -->
```

So the view uses the $scope.filteredData obj to display the list of filtered data. In $scope.showInfoWindow, I'm displaying an infowindow for a map pin that the user clicks on. I then pass the 'site.SiteName' value to the $scope.findSelectedLocations method to loop thru the $scope.filteredData object to find any matches to that location. This part works fine. I can console.table the data and see that itemElement is indeed showing the correct data when the map pin is click (via $scope.showInfoWindow() ).

When I'm having the issue is getting that updated data back in to the view.

In $scope.findSelectedLocations, I'm updating $scope.filteredData with the updated items in itemElement, but the view that displays $scope.filteredData isn't updating. As you can see below, I've tried wrapping that assignment in a $scope.$apply, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `apply()`, that's needed when something out of Angular's context needs to be rendered explicitly in a digest cycle.

May be there's a typo:

Instead of:

```
$scope.filteredData == itemElement;
```

Use:

```
$scope.filteredData = itemElement;
```

And try now.

Angular has two-way data binding. So whenever your model updates, views will automatically be get rendered. Nothing needs to be done explicitly. We have to have a watcher if we want to update the view/logic based on some change detection.

Comment: Yeah, that was how I originally had it and it didn't work. That's why I tried the '==' and wrapping it in $scope.$apply. Just to be sure I tried it again, and no dice.

Comment: Try with just `ng-repeat="data in filteredData`. Also a tip, dont use so much filters in HTML, it will slow down app, move the logic to controllers whenever possible.

Comment: Yep, tried simplifying the ng-repeat to [code]ng-repeat="data in filteredData"[/code],and it still doesn't update when the assignment is made.